# WXPYTHON: How to check If a frame is already visible?

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to prevent a `File -> Preferences` menu from opening multiple copies of itself.  I thought I'd be able to do this with `IsShown()` but it is returning `False` all the time?  With the below snippet, when I use the menu, it opens the frame, and then if it is still open and I use the menu again, it just opens another, but never returns True?

Code snippet:

`def OnPref(self, event):
        frame = PreferencesFrame()
        print frame.IsShown() # Debugging to check Shown() state.
        if frame.IsShown():
            print "already shown"
        else:
            frame.Show(True)`

Comment: I have hacked together a solution using `global` keywords, but I know that's not the proper way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be multiple ways of doing this-

**1.** Normally softwares do not allow access to top-level frames when a settings or preferences window is opened. You might have seen this in many applications. So your best attempt would be to disable the main window before opening the preferences window. This can be done using

```
frame_2 = MyFrame2(None, wx.ID_ANY, "") #frame_2 object is created
frame_2.MakeModal(True) #makes frame_2 our temporary top window. This means that frame_1 cannot be accessed now and can only be accessed after frame_2 is closed
frame_2.Show() #shows frame_2
```

Here we assume that `frame_1` already exists as the top-level window and `frame_2` is being created inside `frame_1`. To make `frame_1` active again after closing `frame_2`, you will have to execute

`self.MakeModal(False)`

Here's how you can do it inside `frame_2`

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_Close)

def on_Close(self, event):
    self.MakeModal(False)  
    frame_1.Show() #frame_1 becomes active again
    event.Skip() #after we have executed our custom set of instructions it is a good idea to skip the event so that python can de-allocate memory and perform other routine tasks
```

**2.** My guess is `IsShown()` works with widgets rather than frames so you may pick up some button or text-box from your preferences frame and use it with `IsShown()` to check if the frame is already visible. This is however an indirect way of achieving what your objective is. You may find the following example useful

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, title='Title', pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(300, 300)):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, pos=(0, 0), size=(300, 300))
        self.b = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Click me!", (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, self.b)
        result = self.b.IsShown()
        print "Button visible? : %s" % (result)

    def OnButton(self, evt):
        self.b.Hide( )
        result = self.b.IsShown()
        print "Button visible? : %s" % (result)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = Frame()
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

def main():
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**3.** Try using `IsShownOnScreen()` for the above example  if `IsShown()` does not work in your case.

Comment: Went with option 1 -- worked great.  Had to realize to set MakeModal(False) in the onClose event.  Thanks!